# Generate a complex grid in WPF programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have working complex grid in wpf written in XAML.

My purpose is to convert the XAML code to c#, so I am going to be able to generate this grid programmatically.

This is the working XAML code

```
<Grid>
<!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=datagrid1, Path=RowHeaderWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column3, Path=ActualWidth}" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column4, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="2">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Super Header!!</Label>
    </Border>
</Grid>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        Name="datagrid1" Grid.Row="1"   Width="10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 1" Width="100" x:Name="Column1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 2" Width="80" x:Name="Column2"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 3" Width="80" x:Name="Column3"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="column 4" Width="*" x:Name="Column4"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>-->
```

When I compile it shows the desire result which looks like 
this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCxAd.png

What I have tried is this :

```
          Grid outernGrid = new Grid();
        outernGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
        RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
        row1.Height = GridLength.Auto;
        RowDefinition row2 = new RowDefinition();
        row2.Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star);
        outernGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);
        outernGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(row2);

        //Second grid
        Grid innerGrid = new Grid();
        ColumnDefinition col0 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();
        ColumnDefinition col4 = new ColumnDefinition();

        //Binding Initialize
        Binding b0 = new Binding { ElementName = "dataGrid2", Path = new PropertyPath("RowHeaderWidth") };
        Binding b1 = new Binding { ElementName = "Column1", Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth") };
        Binding b2 = new Binding { ElementName = "Column2", Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth") };
        Binding b3 = new Binding { ElementName = "Column3", Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth") };
        Binding b4 = new Binding { ElementName = "Column4", Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth") };

        //Set binding
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(col1, DataGrid.ColumnWidthProperty, b1);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(col2, DataGrid.ColumnWidthProperty, b2);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(col3, DataGrid.ColumnWidthProperty, b3);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(col4, DataGrid.ColumnWidthProperty, b4);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(col0, DataGrid.ColumnWidthProperty, b0);

        //Adding columns
        innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col0);
        innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
        innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
        innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);
        innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col4);


        Label header = new Label();
        header.Content = "This is the superheader";




        //Datagrid
        DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid { Name = "dataGrid2" };
        dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGrid.RowHeaderWidth = 10;



        //datagrid columns
        DataGridTextColumn datacol1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridTextColumn datacol2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridTextColumn datacol3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridTextColumn datacol4 = new DataGridTextColumn();

        datacol1.Header = "Column1";
        datacol2.Header = "Column2";
        datacol3.Header = "Column3";
        datacol4.Header = "Column4";


        datacol1.Width = 100;
        datacol1.Width = 80;
        datacol1.Width = 80;
        datacol1.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;

        Grid.SetColumn(header,1);
        header.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty,4);
        Grid.SetRow(innerGrid, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(dataGrid, 1);

        outernGrid.Children.Add(innerGrid);
        outernGrid.Children.Add(dataGrid);
        RootWindow.Content = outernGrid;

    }
```

And the output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mExsT.png)

Can someone help me solving this issue.

Comment: Is this just a learning exercise? Why not just use a DataGrid with header templates and be done with it?

Comment: Can you explain to me how that can be achieved using DataGrid, please ?

Comment: Ah ok I guess I didn't look close enough at first glance. You're just wanting merged headers....well how you show is more or less how I'd know to do it unless you wanted to use a third part DG like Xceed's but I've only ever done this sort of thing in xaml, not c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two observations for you while I attempt to work on this.
First in your code sample you have this:

```
    datacol1.Width = 100;
    datacol1.Width = 80;
    datacol1.Width = 80;
    datacol1.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
```

I imagine you wanted this:

```
    datacol1.Width = 100;
    datacol2.Width = 80;
    datacol3.Width = 80;
    datacol4.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
```

Second, you do not name your columns in the Datagrid programmatically.

You'll have to do something like this for each column:

```
    datacol1.ColumnName = "Column1";
    datacol2.ColumnName = "Column2";
    datacol3.ColumnName = "Column3";
    datacol4.ColumnName = "Column4";
```